# RBS prevents css, layouts, and js not loading

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, remote-blob-storage

I have an existing site collection setup, and have installed and activated RBS on the content DB. Now none of the css, js, or master page layouts are loading. If I disable RBS for the content DB then everything loads fine.

The farm setup is:

- 2 WFE
- 2 Apps
- 1 SQL DB

All servers running Server 2012 R2 Datacenter, SQL Server is SQL Server 2012 SP2. SharePoint is 2013 Ent, SP1 with Dec 2014 CU. have done a full update on Server and SQL server as well.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the web App Pool service account didn't have access (file access) to the RBS storage location.

This step was missing in the guide to configuring RBS for SharePoint. I have found so many missing steps from this guide.